# Getting Author Nickname with Wordpress api

Tags: javascript, wordpress-rest-api

My company has a page on one of our websites(non wordpress site, it's codeigniter) that is using the wordpress api to call our main wordpress website where we have all our employees/writers stored.  They want to display blogs they write and have their information on the page.

Originally I needed the author name and figured out how to get embedded author data like this:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=7903&_embed&per_page=32
```

Then I can get author name as such:

```
var blog_author = response[<?php echo $post_id['pid']; ?>]._embedded.author[0]['name']
```

This works and I can get the authors name, but now they want the nickname displayed on the page too. The nickname is set when a user is added to WordPress and it's a required field so it's got to be accessible somewhere.  However, I've searched the objects and it's not there?

I've searched a solution for a long time, I don't like to just immediately ask stackoverflow but I'm stumped on this one.

Comment: Look at the response from the URL you gave as an example, find the nickname node, and replace 'name' with it

Comment: that's what I'd like to do but that's why I'm asking the question.  Nickname is not in this response

Comment: The link you gave returns what? Please show the response in the question

Comment: probably too many chars to post in a comment... any ideas how I can get you the response?

Comment: haha yep says too long by like 40k chars!

Comment: in the place it should be all it has is this: description
: 
""
id
: 
74
link
: 
"https://www.hiddencom/author/username/"
name
: 
""
slug
: 
""
url
: 
"http://hidden.com"

Comment: logging out of work here but if you can think of a solution I'll see it tomorrow.  i apricate the help anyways.   It's probably some other api call I need to make.  It should be in here though, that would make sense

Comment: I'm not going to guess. I need example data.

Comment: Yea well where it logically should be it's not there.  I put that there a couple of comments ago.   To give you the full response would be like 4k lines...  I guess I'm looking if someone has experience with this and know how to get nickname because it's I guess a different call I need to make.  I do thank you for trying though